# Scalaz sequenceU and IndexStateT compilation issue

Tags: scalaz

I have two functions in the following example code: `runF` and `run`.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future

sealed class Controller[TState]
{
  def genStartState (): TState = ???
  implicit val m = Monoid.instance[Boolean] (_ | _, false)

  def runF ()(implicit f: Monad[Future]) : Future[Boolean] =
  {
    val tasks : List[StateT[Future, TState, Boolean]]
      = ???

    val indexed : IndexedStateT[Future, TState, TState, List[Boolean]]
      = tasks.sequenceU

    val mapped : IndexedStateT[Future, TState, TState, Boolean]
      = indexed.map { results => results.foldMap (identity) }

    val result : Future[Boolean]
      = mapped.eval (genStartState ())

    result
  }

  def run[T[+_]: Monad] () : T[Boolean] =
  {
    val tasks: List[StateT[T, TState, Boolean]]
      = ???

    val indexed: IndexedStateT[T, TState, TState, List[Boolean]]
      = tasks.sequenceU

    val mapped: IndexedStateT[T, TState, TState, Boolean]
      = indexed.map { results => results.foldMap (identity) }

    val result: T[Boolean]
      = mapped.eval (genStartState ())

    result
  }
}
```

`runF` compiles, `run` does not.

I can't work out how to get `run` to compile, I get the following two errors:

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.MonadState[StateTT,CS]
[error]     val monadStateT = MonadState[StateTT, CS]
[error]                                 ^
[error] Implicit not found: scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Applicative, scalaz.StateT[T,TState,Boolean]]. Unable to unapply type `scalaz.StateT[T,TState,Boolean]` into a type constructor of kind `M[_]` that is classified by the type class `scalaz.Applicative`. Check that the type class is defined by compiling `implicitly[scalaz.Applicative[type constructor]]` and review the implicits in object Unapply, which only cover common type 'shapes.'
[error]     = stateTransformers.sequenceU
[error]                         ^
```

The only difference between the two functions is that I am trying to make `runF` generic, so I can use different HKTs.

Comment: Does `T` have to be covariant? Removing the `+` would fix everything much more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I managed to get it working by defining the following implicit Applicative:

```
type ST[α] = StateT[T, TState, α]

implicit val a: Applicative[ST] = new Applicative[ST] {

  def point[A](a: => A): ST[A] =
    StateT ((s: TState) => Applicative[T].point ((s, a)))

  def ap[A, B](fa: => ST[A])(f: => ST[A => B]): ST[B] =
    for { az <- fa; fz <- f } yield fz (az)
}
```